# Java Server Faces Expression Language Evaluate Enum

Tags: jsf, el

Iwant to evaluate an enum in EL in JSF.

The enum is

```
package com.divudi.data;

/**
 *
 * @author Buddhika
 */
public enum InvestigationItemValueType {
    Varchar,
    Memo,
    Double,
    Integer,
    List,
    Image,
    Line,
    Rectangle,
    Circle,

}
```

The EL is

```
                                <h:inputText value="#{pv.strValue}" rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType='Varchar'}" ></h:inputText>
```

The exception is

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: /lab_patient_report_dataentry.xhtml @40,139 rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType='Varchar'}" Error Parsing: #{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType='Varchar'}
root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /lab_patient_report_dataentry.xhtml @40,139 rendered="#{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType='Varchar'}" Error Parsing: #{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType='Varchar'}
root cause

javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{pv.investigationItem.ixItemValueType='Varchar'}
root cause

com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "=" at line 1, column 39.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "(" ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "?" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

Comment: Is the `=` operator listed in the list of expected operators? Why do you keep trying to use it?

Comment: Thank you. Replacing = with == resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closer at the exception message. Is the `=` among the expected operators?

No, it isn't. You're looking for `==`, exactly the operator as you'd use to compare objects in plain Java code. The textual equivalent of this operator is `eq`.

Note that the `==` in EL does under the covers not exactly the same as `==` in Java if one of the both hands is an `Object` instead of a primitive. It would then do exactly the same as `Object#equals()` in Java. In Java, the `==` only compares objects by reference, not by their internal value, you know.